# How to make ProfileCommon play nice with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am converting a webforms site to MVC-3 and am trying to pass my UserProfileModel to a view. However; I am deriving my UserProfileModel class from my custom provider

```
public class UserProfileModel:DFW.Providers.ProfileCommon
{
    public UserProfileModel(string userName,bool IsAuthenticated)
    {
        this.Initialize(userName, IsAuthenticated);

    }
```

Here is the issue, ProfileCommon is not Enumerable therefore I can't do a

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
}
```

What is a simple way to make this play nicely with MVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't, the provider model is not great and does not support constructor injection.